# bind doesn't work after setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Why bind won't work after setInterval?

```
var i = 0;
$('.click').bind('click').click(function(){
 var thisclick = $(this);
  var move = setInterval(function(){
    if(i < 30){
     i++;
     thisclick.unbind('click');
    }
    else{
     thisclick.bind('click');
     clearInterval(move);
    }
  },3000)
})
```

Comment: Simple. Because you don't use it properly. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) takes 2 parameters.

Comment: you should use `$('.click').bind('click', function() {/* */})` or `$('.click').click(function(){/* */})`. Also, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: im trying to animate something, but i dont want to click next when setInterval is running

Comment: `bind` and `click` together?

Comment: i read some post bind the click before unbind. but i already use click()

Comment: You read correct but don't use `click` now, `bind` is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.7 [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is preferred, but the actual issues you have are

1. you are not providing handler for the second binding ( in case you want to rebind the click with the same handler )
2. you need to reset/clear the counter, since it's a closure variable it'll always be in 30 once reached.

   ```
   $('.click').on('click', handler);

   var i = 0;               
   function handler(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var thisclick = $(this);
       var move = setInterval(function () {
           if (i < 10) {
               i++;
               thisclick.off('click');
           } else {
               thisclick.on('click', handler);
               i = 0; // reset here
               clearInterval(move);
           }
       }, 1000);
   };
   ```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eyc3gd0L/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass function and time to setInterval. Like following example and you are missing time is your code.

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")}, 3000);
```

So Change would be

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(i < 30){
     i++;
     thisclick.unbind('click');
    }
    else{
     thisclick.bind('click');
     clearInterval(move);
    }
  },3000)//Give your value here
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding to the click event has nothing to do with the issue.
setInterval() expects two parameters: the function to call when triggered, and the time interval in which to trigger said function (in milliseconds)

For example:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(myFunction, 200);
```

This will trigger the "myFunction" method every 200 milliseconds.